# python approach nested dictionary with 1 variable

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I've found this kind of hard to name this problem, but it must be a simple one and I'm missing something fundamental.

assuming I have the following Python dict() :

```
import json

dct = dict()
dct['hits'] = dict()
dct['hits']['hits'] = dict()
dct['hits']['hits']['a'] = 'b'
dct['hits']['hits']['b'] = 'c'
dct['aggregations'] = dict()
dct['aggregations']['a'] = 1
dct['aggregations']['b'] = 2

print(json.dumps(dct, indent=2))

{
  "hits": {
    "hits": {
      "a": "b",
      "b": "c"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
}
```

This might look familiar because it's the structure of a returned result from ElasticSearch.

I'm building a function that uses that result. But sometimes I want to access `dct['hits']['hits']` And sometimes I want to access `dct['aggregations']`.

Naturally, I'd use a function with a variable suggesting which field I want to access like so:

```
def foo(field):
    return dct[field]
```

And if `field='aggregations'` it's all good. But what do I do when I want the field to be `['hits']['hits']` ?

---

One way to solve it (but it's quite ugly), iterative approach:

```
def foo(fields=('hits','hits')):
    wanted = dct
    for field in fields:
        wanted = wanted[field]
    return wanted

a = foo()
a
Out[47]: {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c'}
a = foo(('aggregations',))
a
Out[51]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

---

The actual function that I'm trying to modify:

```
def execute_scroll_query(es_client, query, indexes):
    try:
        response = es_client.search(index=indexes, scroll='2m', size=1000, body=query)
        scroll_size = len(response['hits']['hits'])
        sid = response['_scroll_id']
        while scroll_size > 0:
            try:
                for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
                    yield hit
                response = es_client.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll='2m')
                sid = response['_scroll_id']
                scroll_size = len(response['hits']['hits'])
            except Exception:
                print("Unexpected Exception while scrolling")
    except Exception:
        print("Unexpected Exception while fetching")
```

Comment: try with a recursive function.(if the element returned is a dict, call the function again until you have a non-dictionary object)

Comment: Iterative approach might solve it in an ugly way.. I'd like something more simple and Pythoic. I'll write that solution though as an example

Comment: then try using the eval function [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: `dct[field]` vs `foo(field)` - seems like you are not really gaining much by having this function

Comment: or maybe the star operator, so you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments to the function.

Comment: @IainShelvington this is just an example so we can focus on the problem.. the real function actually execute a scroll command. You want me to post it?

Comment: That would be helpful. When you want to access the nested key/variable - will the same key be repeated? i.e. dct[field][field] every time?

Comment: @IainShelvington In my particular problem, yes. I'm only handling ['hits']['hits] and ['aggregations']. But I would like to solve it generally

Comment: Posted an answer with a function that will do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce`, but under the hood, it is using iteration and is probably not as efficient as explicit iteration:

```
from functools import reduce

def foo(d, keys):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x[y], keys, d)

foo(dct, ['hits', 'hits', 'a'])
#'b'
```

Comment: That does solve this problem, But I'm aiming for something more Pythonic

Comment: Define "_more pythonic_".

Comment: If the problem was just 1 key, we would solve it with 1 parameter and 1 line.. So a 1 line solution. But come to think of it, We might just build a helper function to get us the desired nested key...

Comment: I do not think a one-line solution is possible.

Comment: you want to tell me python didn't implemented some kind of function that will get list of variables and python dictionary returns the right value for that nested key? :>

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a one-line solution. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This function will recursively lookup keys in the dictionary passed to it `d` and return the last successful lookup

```
def get_nested(d, key):
    result = d.get(key)
    if isinstance(result, dict):
        return result or get_nested(result, key)
    return result
```

Can be called like this

```
get_nested(dct, 'hits')
get_nested(dct, 'aggregations')
```

Comment: Thanks Iain. That ended up to be a stupid question. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
dct = dict()
dct['hits'] = dict()
dct['hits']['hits'] = dict()
dct['hits']['hits']['a'] = 'b'
dct['hits']['hits']['b'] = 'c'
dct['aggregations'] = dict()
dct['aggregations']['a'] = 1
dct['aggregations']['b'] = 2


def foo(dct, *fields):
    n = len(fields)

    for idx in range(n):
        if idx == n - 1:
            return dct[fields[idx]]
        else:
            dct = dct[fields[idx]]


print(foo(dct, 'hits'))    
print(foo(dct, 'hits', 'hits'))
print(foo(dct, 'hits', 'hits', 'a'))
print(foo(dct, 'aggregations'))
print(foo(dct, 'aggregations', 'a'))
```